# Attribute filter with checkboxes , Magento2

Tags: magento2, attributes, layered-navigation, product-list

Has an product attribute filter with checkboxes by default for category view ?

For example

[image]

Comment: will you please explain your question in detail that exactly what do you want?

Comment: I want to show filtering attributes on the category page with checkboxes and filtering with ajax, now it shows with links, is this the default in Magento?

Comment: Magento doesn't provides default ajax feature for the filtering either you need to customize it or you can look for the third part module for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multi select ajax filter are not magento default.

It would be available if your theme has given you the option for this. Otherwise you need to purchase plugin for this

This one is free, ajax based multiselect (Didn't tried it by myself):
https://github.com/NikZh/magento2-multiple-layered-navigation

Mana Dev is free plugin, it allow you to select multiple filters at the same time. But it is not ajax based.
https://www.manadev.com/layered-navigation-filters-multiple-select-magento-2

So if you need ajax based plugin then you need to purchase it. Following are some good ajax based multiselect plugins:

https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-layered-navigation-extension/?gclid=CjwKCAjw4LfkBRBDEiwAc2DSlPjS__1ktEsTo6Geuab4Hqz-VAA7s8H19ALJ7wS9NGiaTnnkDqAVMxoCB34QAvD_BwE

https://bsscommerce.com/magento-2-layered-navigation-extension.html

https://www.weltpixel.com/improved-magento-2-layered-navigation-ajax-filter-multi-select-price-slider.html

Comment: Shoaib Munir, thank You very much

Comment: Updated my answer, added one more plugin which is free. Please vote on my answer too if it is helpful. Thanks for marking it correct :)